# Второй поток начинает свою работу, после завершения первого

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как сделать что бы второй поток запускался после завершения первого потока?

Comment: Дождаться окончания первого потока и потом запускать второй

Comment: это понятно, как это сделать грамотно?

Comment: @СанекКолесников: `первый_поток.Wait(); второй_поток.Start();`. Какие у вас ещё были варианты?

Comment: Сделать все в одном потоке. Смысл от нескольких потоков, если они будут выполняться последовательно?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net

Comment: используется Синхронизация потоков. Надо поискать не надо задавать такие краткие вопросы.

Answer (score -2):

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {action1} ).ContinueWith(() => {action2} );
//здесь может быть много кода
task.Wait();
```

### Почему нужно создавать задания а не потоки?

Для создания потока необходимо много ресурсов и времени, и за чего падает производительность. Когда создаются задания они лезут в пул потоков и берут для выполнения задания уже существующий, простаивающий, поток. Если потока нет тогда он создается. После выполнения задания поток возвращается обратно в пул.
Для текущего кейса оба задания может выполнить один и тот же поток(а может и нет, это как пул потоков захочет).

### Почему иногда следует синхронизировать асинхронные задания?

Если у нас в методе выполняется много других методов то их стоит по возможности распаралелить. Для этого все методы которые могут выполнятся асинхронно необходимо запихнуть в задание. Теперь представьте что в методе 10 вызовов других методов(10 взято из головы для примера и не имеет ничего общего с действительностью) и только 3 из них можно отделить от общей массы и выполнить асинхронно. Но эти 3 метода должны идти друг за другом. И если их просто выполнять друг за другом то весь код станет синхронным, для этого и надо синхронизировать эти 3 метода. В результате мы не будем ожидать по отдельности 3 задания, а будем ожидать общего результата, а пока они будут выполнятся то в текущем потоке выполнятся остальные 7.

Comment: Объясните почему ответ не полезный?

Comment: Например: кусок кода, без пояснений, что в этом коде происходит - не полезен. Таски и потоки - это не одно и то же.

Comment: Потому что ответ не только не отвечает на поставленный вопрос, но и дезинформирует. Почитайте про потоки и таски и их отличия.